# Error when using async Azure Text Analytics

Tags: python, azure, dataframe

I am using async on Azure text analytics, and I have been trying to figure out why my code couldn't work. Here is my code.

```
import os
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
from azure.ai.textanalytics.aio import TextAnalyticsClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

#this is the input list of documents
ace = [{'doc_name': 'doc_1',
        'mention': 'Chris Evans',
        'title': 'Chris Evans',
        'full_text': "Chris Evans started as human torch......."},
        {'doc_name': 'doc_2',
        'mention': 'Tony Stark',
        'title': 'Chris Evans',
        'full_text': "Tony Stark is ironman which likes......."},
        {'doc_name': 'doc_3',
        'mention': 'Chris Evans',
        'title': 'Thor',
        'full_text': "Thor loves to drink......."},
        ....... more docs......
        }]

key = "my-key"
endpoint = "my-endpoint"

azure_client = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))


async def entity_linking(text,doc_name,azure_client):
    
    name = []
    i_d = []
    url = []
    temp = []
    text = []
    doc_n = []
    
    documents = [text]

    try: 
        result = await client.recognize_linked_entities(documents = documents)
        docs = [doc for doc in result if not doc.is_error]

        for doc in docs:

            for entity in result.entities:
                doc_n.append(doc[i]['doc_name'])
                name.append(entity.name)
                i_d.append(entity.data_source_entity_id)
                url.append(entity.url)
                temp.append(entity.matches)

    except Exception as err:
        print("Encountered exception. {}".format(err))
            
            
            
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        text.append(temp[i][0]['text'])
        
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
        'doc_name': doc_n,
        'name': name,
        'id': i_d,
        'text': text,
        'wiki_url': url
    })
        
        
    return dataframe

async def agg_azure_pred(doc, doc_name, azure_client):
    pred_df = pd.DataFrame()

    async with azure_client:

        coro_df = [entity_linking(doc[i]['full_text'],doc[i]['doc_name'], azure_client) for i in range(len(doc))]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*coro_df)

        for df in results:
            pred_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df), pred_df])

    return pred_df 

#I ran the code use this command below
await agg_azure_pred(ace, azure_client)
```

After I ran the code the error I got is `Encountered exception. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'` I am wondering which part of my code has bugs/errors in it, I have been trying to figure but still couldn't solve it. That will be great if any of you here can help me with it.

The output will look something like this

```
doc_name      name            id           text         wiki_url
doc_1      Chris Evans    Chris Evans    Chris Evans     url_1
doc_2      Tony Stark     Tony Stark     Tony Stark      url_2
doc_3         Thor          Thor           Thor          url_3
```

I believe the problem is this line `coro_df = [entity_linking(doc[i]['full_text'],doc[i]['doc_name'], azure_client) for i in range(len(doc))]` I may be doing something wrong about it but I couldn't figure what did I do wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code provided was not runnable as-is, nor could I reproduce the exception you described. I made some tweaks to your code to make it run, but this was without context of what the expected result should be. Please give it a try and see if it helps.

```
import os
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
from azure.ai.textanalytics.aio import TextAnalyticsClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

# this is the input list of documents
ace = [{'doc_name': 'doc_1',
        'mention': 'Chris Evans',
        'title': 'Chris Evans',
        'full_text': "Chris Evans started as human torch......."},
       {'doc_name': 'doc_2',
        'mention': 'Tony Stark',
        'title': 'Chris Evans',
        'full_text': "Tony Stark is ironman which likes......."},
       {'doc_name': 'doc_3',
        'mention': 'Chris Evans',
        'title': 'Thor',
        'full_text': "Thor loves to drink......."}]

key = "my-key"
endpoint = "my-endpoint"

azure_client = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))


async def entity_linking(full_text, doc_name, azure_client):

    name = []
    i_d = []
    url = []
    temp = []
    text = []
    doc_n = []

    documents = [full_text]

    try:
        result = await azure_client.recognize_linked_entities(documents=documents)
        docs = [doc for doc in result if not doc.is_error]

        for doc in docs:
            for entity in doc.entities:
                doc_n.append(doc_name)
                name.append(entity.name)
                i_d.append(entity.data_source_entity_id)
                url.append(entity.url)
                temp.append(entity.matches)

    except Exception as err:
        print("Encountered exception. {}".format(err))

    for i in range(len(temp)):
        text.append(temp[i][0]['text'])

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
        'doc_name': doc_n,
        'name': name,
        'id': i_d,
        'text': text,
        'wiki_url': url
    })

    return dataframe

async def agg_azure_pred(doc, azure_client):
    pred_df = pd.DataFrame()

    async with azure_client:
        coro_df = [entity_linking(doc[i]['full_text'], doc[i]['doc_name'], azure_client) for i in range(len(doc))]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*coro_df)

        for df in results:
            pred_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df), pred_df])

    return pred_df
    # I ran the code use this command below


async def main():
    await agg_azure_pred(ace, azure_client)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
  doc_name                                    name                                      id         text                                           wiki_url
0    doc_3                             Thor (band)                             Thor (band)         Thor          https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(band)
0    doc_2  Tony Stark (Marvel Cinematic Universe)  Tony Stark (Marvel Cinematic Universe)   Tony Stark  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Stark_(Marv...
0    doc_1                     Chris Evans (actor)                     Chris Evans (actor)  Chris Evans  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Evans_(actor)
```

My `pip freeze` from installing `azure-ai-textanalytics`, `aiohttp`, and `pandas`:

```
aiohttp==3.8.1
aiosignal==1.2.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==21.4.0
azure-ai-textanalytics==5.1.0
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.22.1
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
frozenlist==1.3.0
idna==3.3
isodate==0.6.1
msrest==0.6.21
multidict==6.0.2
numpy==1.22.2
oauthlib==3.2.0
pandas==1.4.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.8
yarl==1.7.2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I tried to run it and still threw me the same error. I am guessing its this line```coro_df = [entity_linking(doc[i]['full_text'], doc[i]['doc_name'], azure_client) for i in range(len(doc))]``` that giving me the error. The output is a dataframe contains information from Azure text entity linking

Comment: Are you able to provide more details? Is there other code that is run that is not included in your example? Can you provide the output from a `pip freeze`?

Comment: The output will be a dataframe. I will update the questions with sample output. The code is all there, it works without using async but when I combine everything with async, it is not working. Also, the input documents are in the same format as I provided above

Comment: The entity_linking function contains most of the output based on using Azure build-in functions

Comment: I updated my answer to include the output I see and my pip freeze output. I'm just copying the above code into a sample.py file and running with `python sample.py`.

Comment: Is it because I am using Jupyter Notebook to run it? It is because I will get an error ```async def main():
    await agg_azure_pred(ace, azure_client)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())``` but if I just used ```await agg_azure_pred(ace, azure_client)``` I can run it but giving me the error I mention above

Comment: The error that I get using your code above is ```RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop```

Comment: Ah, didn't know you were running in a notebook (you can remove the code calling main() in that case). How is the code divided into cells? I ran the code under one cell and got the expected output. If I try to run your original code in a notebook it doesn't get further than this line: `await agg_azure_pred(ace, azure_client)` since you are missing a required positional argument. I think there could be an issue with the way your environment is configured. If you can provide more information about your notebook env, including the versions of the packages you are using that would be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242019/discussion-between-codingstark-and-krista).